# Cygwin shows UTC time instead of local time

Tags: timezone, cygwin

Today I noticed my cygwin shell is showing the wrong time. It is actually UTC time while it is supposed to be my local time. As soon as I unset the TZ variable it shows the local time.

Here are some commands which show the situation.
I am running windows 10. My windows has UTC-5:00 timezone and its time is OK.I do not remember when did it start to be like this but my colleagues computers are fine. Has anyone seen this before ?

```
$ date
Mon, Oct 31, 2016  9:13:38 PM

$ date --utc
Mon, Oct 31, 2016  9:13:42 PM


$ echo $TZ
America/Toronto

$ unset TZ

$ date
Mon, Oct 31, 2016  5:13:56 PM

$ cygcheck.exe -V
cygcheck (cygwin) 2.6.0
System Checker for Cygwin
Copyright (C) 1998 - 2016 Cygwin Authors
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

As you might already know, Cygwin sets the timezone in this file :

```
$ tail -1 /etc/profile.d/tzset.sh
test -z "$TZ" && export TZ=$(/usr/bin/tzset)
```

Comment: TZ="America/Toronto" works for me on W7.  Check you have the last tzdata, and follow https://cygwin.com/problems.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  matzeri that pointed out my tzdata, I tried to reinstall tzdata and saw an error about cygintl-8.dll. I searched for that package in Cygwin web site and fount it there:
libintl8-0.19.8.1-2 - libintl8: GNU Internationalization runtime library (installed binaries and support files)
reinstalled the package and problem is resolved.

Comment: You may mark your own answer (click the Grey check mark to turn it Green) on these "self-solve" type questions.