# Time Zone difference between running .py file and directly interacting with Python

Tags: python, datetime

Can anyone tell me why I'm having problems with Python programs showing the incorrect time (it's giving me +5 hrs).

My computer is set correctly for EST. For example, if I went into cygdrive or cmd or powershell and then open up a python command line and do the following, I get the correct time:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> print(datetime.now())
2018-05-15 20:29:28.360810
```

However, if I try to run that same line of code within a .py file and from cygdrive, cmd, or powershell run the below code, I get the wrong date/time:

---In the 'test.py' file---

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())
```

**python test.py**

2018-05-16 01:29:49.636899

Any clues what's going on?

BTW, I'm also getting an error trying to import **pytz**, however when I try a pip install, I get 'requirement already satisfied' with the filepath showing where it is located. Just an FYI, more than anything.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add in this line and try again? `import datetime as dt; print(dt.__file__)`

Comment: It returns as:
`C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\datetime.py`

Comment: Same result when you run it from both the interactive interpreter and `test.py`?

Comment: Sorry I'm just now getting back, @PeterGibson. It's slightly different in the python interpreter (using cygdrive). It returns `/usr/lib/python3.6/datetime.py`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one is running from a windows install and one from within cygwin. This suggests that Cygwin may have a different timezone configured.

Try running `date` in Cygwin to confirm it matches the incorrect time that python is showing. Then take a look at this answer for issues with setting the timezone in Cygwin

[Cygwin shows UTC time instead of local time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40350812/66349)

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue.
Python program gives correct time when run in cmd environment.
The same python program run under cygwin gives London time.
And yet,
echo $TZ gives
America/Los_Angeles
and the command 'date' in cygwin gives Portland time.

Based on another answer, "unset TZ" in the cygwin window fixed the problem.